# Deprecated methods, finding replacement to

Tags: objective-c, ios5, deprecated

I was looking at the `NSURLConnection` class today, specifically researching method:

```
- (void) connection: (NSURLConnection *) conn didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
```

Turns out it is deprecated. **Documentation seems to offer no hints as to the replacement of this method**. How should i proceed finding it please?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, deprecation notices include the replacement method. See [Deprecated UITableViewDelegate Methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html) and [Deprecated NSFileManager Methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html) for an examples. In this case, the documentation is a little confusing, and you should let the doc writers know that. At the bottom of the [web page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html) there's a place to provide feedback.

As other responders have noted, there's little actual change here, since they just moved the old informal protocol into a formal protocol. But the docs are misleading and they should fix it.

Here's a copy of the feedback I've sent:

> This page gives the impression that you shouldn't use these methods anymore. In fact, you should, but they've been moved to a formal protocol. This should be stated more clearly in the deprecation notice.

Answer (score 2):

`connection:didFailWithError:` is still available; it's just been moved to an official protocol (`NSURLConnectionDelegate`). You just need to make sure your class declares that it implements the protocol:

```
@interface YourClass : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDelegate> { ... }
```

Comment: Indeed you are right. Did you search for method declaration in documentation to find this? Is Apple normally publishing these things somewhere?

Comment: I did a search, yes, but Apple's been moving a lot of delegate/datasource things to real protocols since the introduction of the `@optional` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that in IOS5 that informal protocol has been formalised as [NSURLConnectionDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and the documentation sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for `NSURLConnectionDelegate` Protocol.  It looks like that method you're looking for is in there.